# Line Comment in MongoDB config file

Tags: mongodb, configuration, nosql, comments

How to mark a line comment in mongodb configuration file?

```
cpu=true #temporary for dev env
```

Is this the right way?

There is no clue about it in their website page about setting the configuration options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to mark the line a comment, then prepend the hash mark like so:

```
# cpu=true
```

Any line beginning this way will be ignored completely.

Although it is not Windows (which I believe you are running), you can see examples in the Linux [config](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/mongod.conf) [file](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/rpm/mongod.conf) examples.

Comment: It's Windows & it works! Though i needed it for line comment after the config command like in the question itself. Anyway, thanks for the answer.